# After minor refractoring existing android application to new project, home screen icon got removed

Tags: android, google-play

I had my existing android project going unmanageable due to unnecessary research codes, so I decided to create a new project with only necessary code that's required for the app. I uploaded the same on play store's beta environment. As the app got updated on my phone, the already existing app icon on home screen got removed. Did I make any mistake in the code development?

Please help

**EDIT: Added Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="52"
    android:versionName="5.0.004" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.abc.Appname"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.abc.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell since you didn't post any code. In particular, you should at least post the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Did you change the default launcher activity? If so you would want to look into setting up an activity-alias to maintain the launcher icon.

Comment: Yes. I shall post the manifest file once am back home. Sorry about missing that

Comment: I changed the default launcher activity's file name only. Not the activity. But i havr changed the project name. Ex - thefacebook to facebook. Sorry i cant reveal more about the names due to certain constraints.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I have updated the manifest file with the top level code. Remaining code piece of the file lists the different activities.

Comment: 1. If you change a Java file name, you **must** change the class name to match. 2. The AndroidManifest needs to know the fully qualified name of the Activity class.

Comment: Yes. That was also done. I mean even eclipse handled that for me and i checked them manually.

Comment: Also about that fully qualified name. Am sorry i dint get that. The application and activity tags do have the full name, isnt it?

Comment: What i tried newly is that.. I reverted back the application name and the java file. And it started creating the icon while installed from play store's beta env. But not while debugging on a device

Answer (score 0):

Reverted back the application name to old file name (java class) and the same in manifest file. The launcher icon was created while installing via Google play store's beta environment.

Still unsure why the application name and java class names had an impact on the launcher icons. Any idea?